# How to split a string for key value pairs and save them to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below code which works fine to split a string and save key value pairs into a dictionary. Is there a more elegant and efficient way to do the same? Thank you!

```
    private void SplitString()
    {
        string testConfig = "application?test1=value1&test2=value2&test3=value3";

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testConfig) && testConfig.Contains("?"))
        {
            string parameters = testConfig.Substring(testConfig.LastIndexOf("?") + 1);

            string[] parameterArray = parameters.Split(new char[] { '&' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (parameterArray.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in parameterArray)
                {
                    string[] param = item.Split(new char[] { '=' });

                    if (param.Length == 2)
                    {
                        switch (param[0].ToUpper())
                        {
                            case "TEST1":
                                dict.Add("TEST1", param[1]);
                                break;
                            case "TEST2":
                                dict.Add("TEST2", param[1]);
                                break;
                            case "TEST3":
                                dict.Add("TEST3", param[1]);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes. `var dict = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(testConfig)`.

Comment: If you are parsing a URL or a URL-encoded tag/value pair list, I *strongly* recommend you use a proven tool. This problem is harder than it looks. Remember, there are special characters, delimiters, and escape sequences to worry about, and even potential injection threats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to split a query string into a dictionary of query parameters. You should be able to use the [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring) method. Note that this method returns a `NameValueCollection`. That object will probably work for you, but if you need a `Dictionary`, you can use a simple `for` loop to convert the `NameValueCollection` to a `Dictionary`.

Also, if you decide for whatever reason to stick with your original code, you can greatly simplify this code:

```
switch (param[0].ToUpper())
{
    case "TEST1":
        dict.Add("TEST1", param[1]);
        break;
    case "TEST2":
        dict.Add("TEST2", param[1]);
        break;
    case "TEST3":
        dict.Add("TEST3", param[1]);
        break;
}
```

You don't need a separate `case` for each possible value. Instead, you can simply write this:

```
dict.Add(param[0].ToUpper(), param[1]);
```